# R caret / Confusion matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'd like to display the confusion matrix after a train() of the caret library, but I have some doubts. The "train()" should be on a train set ?(I'm not sure because of the "control" parameter). The "predict()" on the test set ? It seems weird to predict on the whole data set...

```
# df_corpus = Document Term Matrix + 1 column of Cos.code(class which are 203.2.2, 204.3.2 ...)
dataset <- df_corpus
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
seed <- 7

metric <- "Accuracy"
preProcess=c("center", "scale")

# Linear Discriminant Analysis
set.seed(seed)
fit.lda <- train(Cos.code~., data=dataset, method="lda", metric=metric,preProc=c("center", "scale"), trControl=control)
ldaClasses <- predict(fit.lda)
cm <- confusionMatrix(data = ldaClasses, dataset$Cos.code)
F1_score(cm$table, "lda")
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the confusion matrix like this:

```
confusionMatrix(predict(fit.lda,dataset$Cos.code),dataset$Cos.code)
```

You can calculate the confusion matrix in the same manner for your testing set, just switch the datasets.

But I believe your model should contain already the information that you want
Examine the information given when printing these two objects.

```
fit.lda

fit.lda$finalModel
```

Comment: I believe that the confusion matrix in your example is actually not right. The first element must be pred and the second must be the truth. from manual: "a factor of predicted classes (for the default method) or an object of class table.
... 
options to be passed to table. NOTE: do not include dnn here
reference 
a factor of classes to be used as the true results"

Comment: You are right. I will update the call to the function. Thank you!